# Hide sap.m.Shell branding bar on top

Tags: css, sapui5

Although I want to use the default blue crystal theme but just want to hide the blue branding bar because I am using native navigation header and network indicator bar in mobile app.

The network indicator bar overlaps with this blue `4px` high bar. Any help please?

[image]

Comment: There is a standard solution provided by the framework: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69312600/5846045

Answer (score 5, accepted):

/* Remove branding bar by changing its height to zero and page header top width to zero */

```
.sapMShellBrandingBar {
    height: 0px;
}

.sapMPageHeader::before {
    border-top-width: 0rem;
}
```

Comment: The custom CSS solution might no longer work in the future if not already. Better apply the standard solution with `sapMBrandingBar-CTX`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69312600/5846045

Answer (score 0):

The bar is set with CSS, you can override it with

```
.sapMPageHeader::before {
    border: none;
}
```

Comment: Although it didn't solve my problem but it gave me a good direction. Check my answer instead.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably too late but still: here is a solution **without using custom CSS** →

in XML:

```xml
<Shell class="sapMBrandingBar-CTX">
```

or in JS:

```js
new Shell({/*...*/}).addStyleClass("sapMBrandingBar-CTX");
```

or in index.html:

```html
<body id="content" class="sapUiBody sapMBrandingBar-CTX">
```

### Advantages

- Simple: apply `sapMBrandingBar-CTX` to either `Shell` directly **or** to one of its parent elements. No custom CSS needed.
- Compatibility: the availability of `sapMBrandingBar-CTX` is covered by the framework's [Unit test](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/f2b0bedf83b0365fc2771ff021bf56e58f0b76c1/src/sap.m/test/sap/m/qunit/Shell.qunit.js#L54-L65) so that there is no regression after migrating to future UI5 releases.

Classes with the suffix `-CTX` (context) are *markers* and can be used appropriately anywhere in your app. `sapMBrandingBar-CTX` is available as of v1.28 ([commit:`1a19dbc`](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/1a19dbcd21b1d89794c28798f5d5fdc8e9f66ab2)).

> This "sapMBrandingBar-CTX" CSS class can be set by any container control that comes with its own branding bar, so any shell inside will not display its branding bar